# Selected Row in ListView/ListFragment in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

In honeycomb the settings app/gmail app has a default selected row on a listview/listfragment and you can scroll on that list and it remains selected. How could this be achieve (do i need to do something on the row xml or the list xml) ? And how do i selected the first one? Is it setSelection( 0 ); on onActivityCreated (listfragment). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to do nothing, this is just a default behavior.